# Why am I unable to close the cookie consent popup on iOS 12.5.7?

Tags: bug, privacy, cookies, browsers, cookie-policy

#### Not a Duplicate

It does not seem to be a duplicate of these:

1. [The cookie consent dialog (coming from cookielaw.org) keeps popping up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362091/the-cookie-consent-dialog-coming-from-cookielaw-org-keeps-popping-up)
2. [Why can't I dismiss these Stack Exchange cookie popups on mobile browser?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363399/why-cant-i-dismiss-these-stack-exchange-cookie-popups-on-mobile-browser)
3. [Why do these buttons (Accept all cookies - Customize settings - review your question) not work on my browser?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382235/why-do-these-buttons-accept-all-cookies-customize-settings-review-your-ques)

#### Environment:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Device | iPhone 6 |
| OS | iOS 12.5.7 |
| Browser | Chrome 92.0.4515.90 |
| Browser | Safari 12.5.7 |

| Apps / Settings | Installed / Turned on |
| --- | --- |
| Firewall | No |
| Antivirus | No |
| Popup blocker | No |
| Ad Blocker | No |
| Chrome > Settings > Content Settings > Block Pop-ups | Off |
| iPhone Settings > Privacy > Advertising > Limit Ad Tracking | Off |
| iPhone Settings > Safari > Block Pop-ops | Off |
| iPhone Settings > Safari > Block All Cookies | Off |
| iPhone Settings > Safari > Advanced > JavaScript | On |

#### Problem

Tapping on Privacy Consent buttons has no effect. It seems like it is a simple `div` or `span` element, not a link or button.

None of the below helped:

1. Logging-in
2. Logging-out
3. Clearing cookies and browsing data
4. Changing the internet connection
5. Connecting to a VPN

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. Visit [stackoveflow.com](https://stackoveflow.com) using Safari or Chrome on iOS 12.5.7 (iPhone 6)
2. Try to close the Privacy Consent popup which tells "**Your privacy**" with three button ("**Accept all cookies**", "**Necessary cookies only**", "**Customize settings**")

#### Safari (iOS) Console log (through iMac Safari Dev Tools)

```
[Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    (anonymous function) (stub.en.js:1)
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: StackExchange
    Global Code (stackoverflow.com:124)
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: StackExchange
    Global Code (stackoverflow.com:127)
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: StackExchange
    Global Code (stackoverflow.com:362)
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: StackExchange
    Global Code (stackoverflow.com:1700)
[Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: StackExchange
    (anonymous function) (animations.en.js:1:9814)
    promiseReactionJob
[Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: StackExchange
    (anonymous function) (lazy-load-images.en.js:1:9814)
    promiseReactionJob
```

Comment: It is an older browser without support for the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/operators/optional_chaining) operator: [Stack Exchange changes broke UI on multiple legacy browsers - Again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376694/stack-exchange-changes-broke-ui-on-multiple-legacy-browsers-again). The [staff answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377911/377214) says that they can't go through and change every other instance of it to support legacy browsers.

Comment: AFAIK this is not called poor compatibility. This is a terrible UX mistake to fill half a 4" screen with an annoying and non-removable popup only to say we concern about your privacy. It could be simply ignored for the devices which they call old or legacy. Downvote for the Stack Overflow.

Comment: The iPhone 6 was discontinued 7 years ago. How's your battery holding up?

Comment: @Mast Batteries are parts and parts can get replaced. Do you throw your car away, when its tires have no more remaining tread?